# spring jpa - way to get recordId from parent table while inserting into child table

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables (parent & child). 
Parent table has some rows inserted already.
Now, i am inserting into child table.

is there any way in Spring JPA where insertion in child table gets corresponding ID from parent table based on query.

Don't want to make read call from to parent and then insert call to Child.. looking for a way to happen this with single insert

Below is how my mapping from Child entity class looks....

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Parent.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "childId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Parent parent;
```

Comment: Sure if you map the relationship. How does your mapping look like?

Comment: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Parent.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "childCol", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
 private Parent parent;

Comment: Do you know the ID of Parent?

Comment: Yes.. The primary key is "id" in Parent entity class

Comment: I mean the value of the parent entity id. Please checkout my answer

Answer (score 0):

If yo know the ID of `PartnerCountry` then you don't need to load the `PartnerCountry`.

You can call `getReference()` on the EntityManager:

```
ParentCountry parentCountry = entityManager.getReference(ParentCountry.class, parentCountryId);
child.setParentCountry(parentCountry);
```

This code will not select `ParentCountry` from the database. `getRefrence()` returns a Proxy that is used to set the foreign key.

Unfortunately JpaRepository does not expose getReference() so you have to inject the EntityManager where you save the child.

Form the Hibernate docs.

> getReference() obtains a reference to the entity. The state may or may
>   not be initialized. If the entity is already associated with the
>   current running Session, that reference (loaded or not) is returned.
>   If the entity is not loaded in the current Session and the entity
>   supports proxy generation, an uninitialized proxy is generated and
>   returned, otherwise the entity is loaded from the database and
>   returned.

Comment: Thank you for quick response Simon. I don't know the ID value here, i have the other parameters based on which ID value has to be brought here. and this ID should be used to store into foreign key column in child table. is that possible?

Comment: Ah but then you need to do a select anyway to the the ParentCountry. so just fetch this. Or you could create a query that returns just the id and use the code of my answer